# Idiom about something being very different

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, differences, idioms, idiom-requests

I need an idiom for two things being very different in amount (price) for negotiating.

I’m trying to remember something along the lines of moon and ground/sky and ground, but I can’t remember the exact idiom/phrase.

The point is to highlight two prices being very different (one very high the other one very low)

Tried googling it but found nothing.

It’s really simple I just can’t remember it.

Ideas guys?

EDIT: context, I want to say “The price is negotiable, as long as it’s not ________ and __________, where the first is something really high and the other one is something really low, to highlight the difference.
Hopefully that make it clearer.

Comment: Idioms.  apples and oranges; ie., for both Two unlike things or people /idioms.thefreedictionary.com  Use: There's an apples and oranges price difference on these two item's price.  You can download & peruse UK idioms here: https://www.easypacelearning.com/english-books/english-books-for-download-pdf/category/6-english-grammar-pdf-and-word-doc

Comment: Check out the answer edit

Comment: It's not possible for it to be both high and low at the same time. Are you sure you don't mean to say **or**? Plus, if I were buying, why would I think something was wrong with a low price—and if I were selling, why would I think something was wrong with a high price? I can't think of any saying here that would actually make sense.

Comment: It’s not both high and low, it’s 2 objects one is high the other low. It’s simple, I named a price someone asked if it’s negotiable, I’m saying “Yes, as long as it’s not A and B”. A is something high like moon and B is something low like ground or something. How does that not make sense?

Comment: It's common to say `The price is slightly negotiable`. Refer to [examples from a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="slightly+negotiable").

Answer (score 1):

Two contrasting idioms are "**sky high**" and "**dirt cheap**". Would you consider using these two? Each is short, and they can be easily used together. Both match your description (except for the moon part). Both are frequently used in "price negotiations" as well.

> "You're not fooling me with fast talk. The price you want is not
>   "**dirt cheap**", it's "**sky high**" for sure. Get it lower  - then and I *might* take the bait."

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sky-high

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dirt+cheap

Comment: Not quite, here’s some more context. I was asked if the price is negotiable, what I’m saying is “Yes, as long as it’s not ________ and ________”, where first is something really high and the second something really low, hopefully that makes it clearer

Comment: Now w/detail - try web search on Business English Idioms and expressions.

Comment: Tried that before, it’s surprising that nothing pops up, it’s so simple and known, nothing to do with business though

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I was searching for variations on idioms for “the difference is like black-and-white” and found this.

This is confusing and frankly makes no sense, and the original question asked (and explained again) is very contradictory. Your only concern would be offers that are too low, yes? If you (as the seller) reply back, you would not say “yes the price is negotiable, as long as you don’t shoot me a price that’s TOO HIGH or TOO LOW” you would just simply say “yes, but no lowball offers.”

What you’re suggesting is that you would NOT accept more money than your original asking price on the item (why wouldn’t you? But why would a potential buyer even do that?) Price negotiation means you’ll only get an offer LOWER than your original asking price. The exception would be a bidding war over a high demand item, but that doesn’t sound like what’s described here.